# Is there a way to depict using matrix operations or equivalent, the practice of z-culling in a 3D-to-2D render algorithm

Tags: geometry, 3d

To clarify, the purpose of the question is to try and identify (if possible) a way to accomplish the entire 3D-to-2D projection/render process, including the z-buffering and depth-culling steps, using a chain of matrix multiplication/addition or equivalent operations.

Note: "Simply not possible" would be an acceptable answer, if accurate.

Answer (score 0):

A way to visualize *perspective* projections is to imagine the camera as consisting of a plane $P$ (the "film") plus a single point $F$ (the "lens") that does not lie on P.

To find the image $I_X \in P$ of an arbitrary point $X$, you intersect the (unique!) line that contains $X$ and $P$ with the plane $P$ -- the point of intersection is then $I_X$.

For *orthogonal* projections (in place of *perspective* ones), you only need $P$, and instead of picking lines through $X$ and $F$, you pick lines *orthogonal* to $P$ and going through $X$.

In reality, you usually want to project arbitrary surfaces and not only points. The standard approach to that is to first split the surface into a number of triangles. Each triangle is then projected onto the image area separately. Note that, since the projections described above have the property that they map *straight lines* to *straight lines*, a triangle can be projected by simply projecting its vertices! The resulting triangle in the image plane is then colored with whatever color the triangle is supposed to have (I'm ignoring lighting and texturing here!).

To deal with overlapping objects, each pixel in the image plane is associated with a $z$-Value, in addition to the three color values $R$,$G$ and $B$. When projecting a triangle, you then do the following steps

1. Project the three vertices $v_1, v_2, v_3$, and for each vertex $v_i$ determine the distance $d_i$ between the vertex and the lense
2. Loop over the pixels within the triangle created by the projected vertices in the image plane.

   1. Find the distance $d$ corresponding to the current pixel by interpolating between $d_1, d_2$ and $d_3$. Or alternatively, find $d$ by reverse-projecting the pixel onto the original triangle.
   2. Compare $d$ to the pixel's $z$-value. If the $z$-value is less than $d$, skip the pixel
   3. Otherwise, color the pixel in the triangle's color, and store $d$ in the pixel's $z$-value.

Depth culling is a optimization of this procedure -- you tried to skip whole triangles (or even whole objects) if you can determine before-hand that *all* their pixels will fail the depth test. But unless you're dealing with very simply scenes, you'll usually still need a $z$-Buffer -- triangles are usually allowed to overlap *partially*, and depth culling techniques usually won't be able to deal with that correctly on their own.

Comment: This is nice. But is there a way to extend this visualization to a whole collection of points? I mean a succinct mathematical description of the overall process of the creation of an image (via a lens like you described - I don't know why I missed that!) on a 2D plane from a 3D field of objects (or in other words, a 2D projection of a 3D field of points, with some points occluded by others based on depth)?

Comment: @DevKanchen I've extended my answer to explain how a $z$-Buffer is used to deal with (partially) occluded objects. This is the most general technique (that I know of) to deal with occlusion -- most other techniques like culling are simply optimizations that are done on top of that...

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I wasn't clear. I actually understand the ALGORITHM, and the logic completely. What I was looking for something like - say a perspective transform can be expressed using an equation like I = P x O where O is a matrix having all the points belonging to the object I want to render, P is the perspective transform matrix and I is the transformed result. So a perspective transform is MATHEMATICALLY expressible as simply a matrix multiplication. One doesn't need to know what I, O or P are in the real world.

Comment: Similarly, what would be the set of MATHEMATICAL expressions that explain the render process, rather than the logical steps (e.g. The whole z-buffering process is a LOGICAL one of CHOOSING which "d" to use out of a list of them). Instead is there a set of SELF-CONTAINED mathematical expressions, perhaps linear/matrix equations that COMPLETELY define the render process, without the need for if/else conditions etc which basically require a computer or human "processor" to "add x objects to array, now compare them" and so on.

Comment: Like I said, I'm not sure what I'm asking for is even possible (series of succinct and general mathematical operations such as matrix multiplication or some other operations), or it can be expressed only as an "algorithm", including if-then conditions, looping, etc.  Note: I'm aware the basic perspective transform etc ARE matrix mult operations - what I want to understand is if the IDEA of the creation of an image can be expressed in purely mathematical terms.

Comment: @DevKanchen There is nothing un-mathematical about an algorithmn... In fact, you can translate *any* algorithm into a system of (recursively) defined functions which use nothing but 0, 1 and "+".

Comment: I think this is the part I don't understand. Could you point me to a wikipedia or some other resource that can explain this part better (mathematical description of algorithms using functions, etc). Sorry for the n00bishness.

Comment: additionally, I think I went too long-winded with the question. A simpler restatement of my intent with the question would be - "Is it possible to perform 3D-2D orthographic (or any other) projection, including depth-culling, using only matrix operations". And "If not matrix operations, any other tools, other than the default algorithms, are also welcome". I could delete this question and reask if it helps clean up this mess in the comments. Thanks for your time though, I do appreciate it.

Comment: instead of deleting the question I have edited it completely. Please feel free to post another answer appropriate to the modified question and I'll mark as answered and wrap this up. Thank you for your time here - the projection explanation was pretty nice but sadly not what I was looking for in my misframed question.